# Libgdx scene2d.ui InputListener for custom Actor not working

Tags: java, libgdx, actor, event-listener, scene2d

I am trying to use the Libgdx Scene2dui library and want to catch the mouse touchdown event.  I have a custom Actor and a dialog that instantiates an instance of the Actor and tries to listen for touch events.  For some reason the touch events are not getting caught.

```
public class MMADialog136WhiteCanvasActor extends Actor {

    public MMADialog136WhiteCanvasActor () {
        super();
        setWidth(256);
        setHeight(256);
        setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        mMyRenderer = new ImmediateModeRenderer10();
    }

   @Override
    public Actor hit(float arg0, float arg1, boolean flag) {
        return null;
        }

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float arg1) {
         batch.end();
        Vector3 pos0 = new Vector3(1,1,0);
        Vector3 pos1 = new Vector3(100,100,0);
        mMyRenderer.begin(GL10.GL_LINES);        
        mMyRenderer.color(mColor.r,mColor.g,mColor.b,mColor.a);
        mMyRenderer.vertex(pos0);
        mMyRenderer.vertex(pos1);                                       
        mMyRenderer.end();
         batch.begin();
    }
    private ImmediateModeRenderer10 mMyRenderer;
    private Color mColor = MMAColor.MMAWHITE;
}
```

And the Actor instance listener...

```
mWhiteCanvas.addListener(new InputListener() {
    public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        System.out.println("x,y" + x + "," + y);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Any idea why the InputListener is not catching the event?

My initial thought was the Actor draw space needs bounds, so I added the setBounds() based on predefined width=256 and height=256, but this has no effect.

Comment: Did you set the stage as the Input Processor?

Comment: Yes stage is an InputProcessor so this Actor does get focus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public Actor hit(float arg0, float arg1, boolean flag) {
    return null;
}
```

This is the problem. By always returning `null` you basically say that this actor is never hit. And it will never receive any enter, click, exit, keydown or other events.

If you want a standard bounding box test, then do this instead:

```
@Override
public Actor hit(float arg0, float arg1, boolean flag) {
    return super.hit(arg0, arg1, flag);
}
```

I'd also advice you to get the sources to your code. `arg0` doesn't seem to help anyhow and you also don't have any JavaDoc I suppose. Otherwise you would probably know what the `hit()` method does. Because it is well documented.